# Как сохранить таблицу html

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал таблицу в html
*(Имя,код паспорта,номер телефона, сумма, "не погашено/погашено")*
Суть такова что надо чтоб при нажатие на имя вылезало окошко, с "погасить?" при нажатие ок, текст в последней ячейке строки меняется на "погашено" это я сделал.
Но при обновлении страницы все данные слетают.
Не могу не как реализовать сохранения хотя пытался через localStorage но я в нём вообще не бум бум.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Кредиты </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div  class="clearfix">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <h  align="left">Служебный код:</h><h id="r"></h>
  <h1  align="center">Меню кредитора</h1>
 <div class="serch">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Поиск.." title="Введите имя">
 </div>
<table id="_myTable" class="tablica"  align="center">
  <th>ФИО</th>
  <th>Код паспорта</th>
  <th>Номер телефона</th>
  <th>Сума</th>
  <th>Статус</th>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Емельянов Семен Федорович</td>
        <td>906170903</td>
        <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
        <td>345 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Етухов Орест Мелорович</td>
        <td>829973997</td>
        <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
        <td>7000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Дроздов Оскар Михаилович</td>
        <td>045271762</td>
        <td>+38(097)910-56-88110</td>
        <td>1000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ефимов Фрол Витальевич</td>
        <td>255710705</td>
        <td>+38(097)851-83-87932</td>
        <td>200 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Антонов Касьян Вячеславович</td>
        <td>607263728</td>
        <td>+38(097)773-22-79478</td>
        <td>100 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Кузнецов Вольдемар Артёмович</td>
        <td>291346172</td>
        <td>+38(097)743-62-47225</td>
        <td>800 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Филиппов Ибрагил Александрович</td>
        <td>874756345</td>
        <td>+38(097)441-21-15443</td>
        <td>900 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Пахомов Яков Семенович</td>
        <td>815401771</td>
        <td>+38(097)754-54-92350</td>
        <td>2500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Миронов Вилли Ярославович</td>
        <td>426823330</td>
        <td>+38(097)869-33-25909</td>
        <td>4500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Яковлев Парамон Никитевич</td>
        <td>862986579</td>
        <td>+38(097)225-47-08116</td>
        <td>100 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Иванков Адам Авдеевич</td>
        <td>781931117</td>
        <td>+38(097)511-53-40428</td>
        <td>350 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Никифоров Афанасий Геласьевич</td>
        <td>268904042</td>
        <td>+38(097)224-58-45888</td>
        <td>3500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Устинов Рубен Давидович</td>
        <td>780312808</td>
        <td>+38(097)428-41-95761</td>
        <td>1000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Киселёв Мирослав Ростиславович</td>
        <td>201935118</td>
        <td>+38(097)762-27-75687</td>
        <td>4000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Фомин Василий Валерьевич</td>
        <td>921105431</td>
        <td>+38(097)326-78-46650</td>
        <td>2000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Гущин Елисей Тимофеевич</td>
        <td>610390795</td>
        <td>+38(097)341-20-89276</td>
        <td>450 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Морозов Арсен Аристархович</td>
        <td>409729583</td>
        <td>+38(097)996-64-35218</td>
        <td>1300 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Евдокимов Владимир Гордеевич</td>
        <td>547297372</td>
        <td>+38(097)853-21-07291</td>
        <td>10000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Филиппов Аркадий Альбертович</td>
        <td>369634473</td>
        <td>+38(097)048-93-06006</td>
        <td>2000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Мышкин Демьян Валерьевич</td>
        <td>266605642</td>
        <td>+38(097)734-08-61619</td>
        <td>1300 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
<script>
var min=999999;
var max=10000000;
document.getElementById("r").textContent=min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));

var table = document.getElementById('_myTable');
for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
               {
                   table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                   {

                     if (confirm("Погасить?")) {
                         txt = "Погашено";
       localStorage.setItem(i,"Погашено");
       let value = localStorage.getItem(i);
       console.log(value)
                       }
        else{
        txt = "не погашено";
          localStorage.setItem(i,"не погашено");
       let value = localStorage.getItem(i);
       console.log(value)
        }
                        this.cells[4].innerHTML=txt;
                   };
               }
      
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, k, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("_myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (k = 0; k < tr.length; k++) {
    td = tr[k].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[k].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[k].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
#container{

}
body{background-image: url(images/paper.jpg);}
#header{

}
.tablica{
    background-color: white;
    border-spacing: 30px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.tablica tr td{
 padding: 5px 10px;
   }
   td:hover{background-color:green;cursor: pointer}
   th {
       background: #afd792; /* Цвет фона */
       color: #333;  /* Цвет текста */
      }
     tr:hover {
       background: green; /* Цвет фона при наведении */
       color: #fff; /* Цвет текста при наведении */
      }
.serch{
 margin-top:2%;
 padding-left:28%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Кредиты </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div  class="clearfix">
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <h  align="left">Служебный код:</h><h id="r"></h>
  <h1  align="center">Меню кредитора</h1>
 <div class="serch">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Поиск.." title="Введите имя">
 </div>
<table id="_myTable" class="tablica"  align="center">
  <th>ФИО</th>
  <th>Код паспорта</th>
  <th>Номер телефона</th>
  <th>Сума</th>
  <th>Статус</th>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Емельянов Семен Федорович</td>
        <td>906170903</td>
        <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
        <td>345 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Етухов Орест Мелорович</td>
        <td>829973997</td>
        <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
        <td>7000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Дроздов Оскар Михаилович</td>
        <td>045271762</td>
        <td>+38(097)910-56-88110</td>
        <td>1000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ефимов Фрол Витальевич</td>
        <td>255710705</td>
        <td>+38(097)851-83-87932</td>
        <td>200 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Антонов Касьян Вячеславович</td>
        <td>607263728</td>
        <td>+38(097)773-22-79478</td>
        <td>100 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Кузнецов Вольдемар Артёмович</td>
        <td>291346172</td>
        <td>+38(097)743-62-47225</td>
        <td>800 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Филиппов Ибрагил Александрович</td>
        <td>874756345</td>
        <td>+38(097)441-21-15443</td>
        <td>900 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Пахомов Яков Семенович</td>
        <td>815401771</td>
        <td>+38(097)754-54-92350</td>
        <td>2500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Миронов Вилли Ярославович</td>
        <td>426823330</td>
        <td>+38(097)869-33-25909</td>
        <td>4500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Яковлев Парамон Никитевич</td>
        <td>862986579</td>
        <td>+38(097)225-47-08116</td>
        <td>100 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Иванков Адам Авдеевич</td>
        <td>781931117</td>
        <td>+38(097)511-53-40428</td>
        <td>350 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Никифоров Афанасий Геласьевич</td>
        <td>268904042</td>
        <td>+38(097)224-58-45888</td>
        <td>3500 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Устинов Рубен Давидович</td>
        <td>780312808</td>
        <td>+38(097)428-41-95761</td>
        <td>1000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Киселёв Мирослав Ростиславович</td>
        <td>201935118</td>
        <td>+38(097)762-27-75687</td>
        <td>4000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Фомин Василий Валерьевич</td>
        <td>921105431</td>
        <td>+38(097)326-78-46650</td>
        <td>2000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Гущин Елисей Тимофеевич</td>
        <td>610390795</td>
        <td>+38(097)341-20-89276</td>
        <td>450 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Морозов Арсен Аристархович</td>
        <td>409729583</td>
        <td>+38(097)996-64-35218</td>
        <td>1300 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Евдокимов Владимир Гордеевич</td>
        <td>547297372</td>
        <td>+38(097)853-21-07291</td>
        <td>10000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Филиппов Аркадий Альбертович</td>
        <td>369634473</td>
        <td>+38(097)048-93-06006</td>
        <td>2000 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Мышкин Демьян Валерьевич</td>
        <td>266605642</td>
        <td>+38(097)734-08-61619</td>
        <td>1300 uah</td>
        <td>не погашено</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</tbody></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var min = 999999;
var max = 10000000;
document.getElementById("r").textContent = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));

var table = document.getElementById('_myTable');
for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(i)) {
    table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(i);
  }
  table.rows[i].onclick = function() {

    let txt;
    if (this.cells[4].textContent != 'Погашено') {

      if (confirm("Погасить?")) {
        txt = "Погашено";
        localStorage.setItem(i, "Погашено");
        let value = localStorage.getItem(i);
        console.log(value)
      } else {
        txt = "не погашено";
        localStorage.setItem(i, "не погашено");
        let value = localStorage.getItem(i);
        console.log(value)
      }

      this.cells[4].innerHTML = txt;
    }


  };

}

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, k, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("_myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (k = 0; k < tr.length; k++) {
    td = tr[k].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[k].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[k].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {}

body {
  background-image: url(images/paper.jpg);
}

#header {}

.tablica {
  background-color: white;
  border-spacing: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.tablica tr td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer
}

th {
  background: #afd792;
  /* Цвет фона */
  color: #333;
  /* Цвет текста */
}

tr:hover {
  background: green;
  /* Цвет фона при наведении */
  color: #fff;
  /* Цвет текста при наведении */
}

.serch {
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 28%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Кредиты </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <h align="left">Служебный код:</h>
        <h id="r"></h>
        <h1 align="center">Меню кредитора</h1>
        <div class="serch">
          <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Поиск.." title="Введите имя">
        </div>
        <table id="_myTable" class="tablica" align="center">
          <th>ФИО</th>
          <th>Код паспорта</th>
          <th>Номер телефона</th>
          <th>Сума</th>
          <th>Статус</th>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Емельянов Семен Федорович</td>
              <td>906170903</td>
              <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
              <td>345 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Етухов Орест Мелорович</td>
              <td>829973997</td>
              <td>+38(097)534-41-45371</td>
              <td>7000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Дроздов Оскар Михаилович</td>
              <td>045271762</td>
              <td>+38(097)910-56-88110</td>
              <td>1000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ефимов Фрол Витальевич</td>
              <td>255710705</td>
              <td>+38(097)851-83-87932</td>
              <td>200 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Антонов Касьян Вячеславович</td>
              <td>607263728</td>
              <td>+38(097)773-22-79478</td>
              <td>100 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Кузнецов Вольдемар Артёмович</td>
              <td>291346172</td>
              <td>+38(097)743-62-47225</td>
              <td>800 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Филиппов Ибрагил Александрович</td>
              <td>874756345</td>
              <td>+38(097)441-21-15443</td>
              <td>900 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Пахомов Яков Семенович</td>
              <td>815401771</td>
              <td>+38(097)754-54-92350</td>
              <td>2500 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Миронов Вилли Ярославович</td>
              <td>426823330</td>
              <td>+38(097)869-33-25909</td>
              <td>4500 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Яковлев Парамон Никитевич</td>
              <td>862986579</td>
              <td>+38(097)225-47-08116</td>
              <td>100 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Иванков Адам Авдеевич</td>
              <td>781931117</td>
              <td>+38(097)511-53-40428</td>
              <td>350 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Никифоров Афанасий Геласьевич</td>
              <td>268904042</td>
              <td>+38(097)224-58-45888</td>
              <td>3500 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Устинов Рубен Давидович</td>
              <td>780312808</td>
              <td>+38(097)428-41-95761</td>
              <td>1000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Киселёв Мирослав Ростиславович</td>
              <td>201935118</td>
              <td>+38(097)762-27-75687</td>
              <td>4000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Фомин Василий Валерьевич</td>
              <td>921105431</td>
              <td>+38(097)326-78-46650</td>
              <td>2000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Гущин Елисей Тимофеевич</td>
              <td>610390795</td>
              <td>+38(097)341-20-89276</td>
              <td>450 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Морозов Арсен Аристархович</td>
              <td>409729583</td>
              <td>+38(097)996-64-35218</td>
              <td>1300 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Евдокимов Владимир Гордеевич</td>
              <td>547297372</td>
              <td>+38(097)853-21-07291</td>
              <td>10000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Филиппов Аркадий Альбертович</td>
              <td>369634473</td>
              <td>+38(097)048-93-06006</td>
              <td>2000 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Мышкин Демьян Валерьевич</td>
              <td>266605642</td>
              <td>+38(097)734-08-61619</td>
              <td>1300 uah</td>
              <td>не погашено</td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </tbody>

</html>
```

Подшаманил ваш код.

Когда вы с помощью цикла вешаете обработчик на каждую строку, используйте **локальную переменную `let`**. Т.к. при использовании `var` обработчик будет повешен только на последний 21(не существующий у вас) элемент. Вообще, при наличии однотипных действий вместо цикла лучше использовать **делегирование**.